# Java Program Runs, but No GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm learning Java and tried to make a program. The program runs fine, but the GUI doesn't appear! The concept is to enter a number from 1 to 10, then it sends you a message. I worked out how to do that in the console, but am trying to get it to work in a GUI.
Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class App extends JFrame {
JLabel label;
JTextField tf;
JButton button;

    public App () {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("On a scale of 1 to 10, how are you feeling today?");
        add(label);
        tf = new JTextField(10);
        add(tf);
        button = new JButton("Enter");
        add(button);

        event e = new event();
        button.addActionListener(e);
    }
    public class event implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                String word =tf.getText();
                FileWriter stream = new FileWriter("~/Library/Application Support/Cookies160/file.txt");
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(stream);
                out.write(word);
                out.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        App gui = new App();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setSize(300,150);
        gui.setTitle("My Program");
        gui.setVisible(true);

     {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("On a scale of 1 to 10, how are you feeling today?");
    int line = input.nextInt();

    if (line < 5) {
        System.out.println("Really? I hope it gets better!");
    }

    if (line == 7) {
        System.out.println("That's good to hear!");
    }

    if (line == 8) {
        System.out.println("That's good to hear!");
    }

    if (line == 9) {

        System.out.println("That's good to hear!"); 
    }

    if (line == 10) {
        System.out.println("That's good to hear!");
    }

    if (line == 5) {
        System.out.println("Hmm... You should try to have more fun!");
    }

    if (line == 6) {
        System.out.println("Hmm... You should try to have even just a bit more fun!");
    }

    if (line < 0) {
        System.out.println("Oh?... Well, I hope it gets much better!");
    }

    if (line > 10) {
        System.out.println("Ha, I love people with your kind of enthusiasm!");
    }
    if (line == 42) {
        System.out.println("It's also great to see that your feeling full of life!");
    }

    if (line == 69) {
        System.out.println("Also,... -_-");
    }
}}}
```

Comment: You should clean up your brackets

Comment: The structure of your code is off. For example you have your scanner outside of your main method. Are you following a book?

Comment: @Rogue fair enough, but the program runs fine, so that's not the problem

Comment: @user3149832 I thought it didn't run fine, which is why you're posting a question on StackOverflow about it.

Comment: @KamRon I'm following multiple tutorials, as well as some online lectures.

Comment: @user3149832 it runs fine but it isn't correct.

Comment: @KamRon using an opening bracket with no context is equivalent to just changing the scope. It's still within the method but it's messy.

Comment: @djechlin The program will run IN THE CONSOLE, but the GUI just won't appear

Comment: @Rouge Thanks I looked at that to quickly you are correct.

Comment: `catch(Exception ex) {}` you should probably log the exception instead of ignore it, especially if, say, something is going wrong, and you don't know what

Comment: You are mixing GUI-Components with command line stuff. You should either use System.in or the TextField as input.

Comment: And Swing components *must* be manipulated from the event dispatch thread, not from the main thread. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: @keuleJ So, I should have the code in a separate class?

Comment: You shouldn't use Scanner and System.in if you want to read the input from a JTextField. Of maybe you should explain us what the program should do exactly...

Comment: @keuleJ The program asks you how your day is going on a scale of 1 to 10. Responding with certain numbers get a certain response. The idea of the GUI is to have an input (for your number), an enter button (self-explanatory) and an output (console/response).

Answer (score 0):

You're not packing your frame at any point.  Have a look at [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) to get started with Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App extends JFrame {
    JLabel label;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton button;
    private JLabel answerLabel;

    public App() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("On a scale of 1 to 10, how are you feeling today?");
        add(label);
        tf = new JTextField(10);
        add(tf);
        button = new JButton("Enter");
        add(button);
        answerLabel = new JLabel();
        add(answerLabel);

        ActionListenerImpl e = new ActionListenerImpl();
        button.addActionListener(e);
    }

    public class ActionListenerImpl implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                String answer = getAnswer(tf.getText());
                answerLabel.setText(answer);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException,
            InterruptedException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                App gui = new App();
                gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                gui.setSize(300, 150);
                gui.setTitle("My Program");
                gui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private String getAnswer(String input) {

        int line = Integer.parseInt(input);

        if (line < 5) {
            return "Really? I hope it gets better!";
        }

        if (line == 7) {
            return "That's good to hear!";
        }

        if (line == 8) {
            return "That's good to hear!";
        }

        if (line == 9) {

            return "That's good to hear!";
        }

        if (line == 10) {
            return "That's good to hear!";
        }

        if (line == 5) {
            return "Hmm... You should try to have more fun!";
        }

        if (line == 6) {
            return "Hmm... You should try to have even just a bit more fun!";
        }

        if (line < 0) {
            return "Oh?... Well, I hope it gets much better!";
        }

        if (line > 10) {
            return "Ha, I love people with your kind of enthusiasm!";
        }
        if (line == 42) {
            return "It's also great to see that your feeling full of life!";
        }

        if (line == 69) {
            return "Also,... -_-";
        }
        return "???";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might call the method

```
gui.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Comment: This wreaks of 'programming by magic'.  And this time, the spell not only fails, but shoves a broken GUI in the user's face.  -1